# What is the difference between Uses, reads and writes in User Activity?

Tags: ibm-domino

I have to produce a report on user activity for all of the Domino apps I support.

If you examine the "User Detail" for Activity via the NSF properties you see Uses, Reads, Writes.  What is a "Use" defined as?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Help database:

> The User Activity dialog box shows each database user or server
>   session, and how many documents a user or server read or wrote during
>   each session, with the most recent activity appearing at the top of
>   the list.
>
> At the bottom of the user activity summary are the total database
>   usage statistics for the prior day, week, and month, and since user
>   activity recording began.
>
> Note The information presented in this dialog box is the same as in
>   the Notes Log, Database Usage, and Database Activity Log Entry.
>
> "Reads," "Writes," and "User" are defined as follows:
>
> - Reads: Number of times users opened documents and number of times    servers read documents.
> - Writes: Number of times users and servers    created, modified, or deleted documents.
> - User: Number of times users    or servers accessed the database and performed at least one read or write.

I found this in the 7.0 Help database. The details of reads, writes and user/uses is not described like this in the 8.x Help database.

Comment: Thanks Per!  That appears to line up right with the activity screen.  7 Help indeed!

Comment: Nice. 
In user activity dialog, you can see the column "deletes". I wonder where is that info stored. I can't find that info ("deletes") in log.nsf > Database > Usage.